# Easily declaring java lambdas of intersectional types

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's say I have a method like the following:

```
public <T extends Supplier<Collection<String>> & Serializable> void doSomething(T supplier){
    new ArrayList<String>().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
}
```

Why is it that

```
doSomething(() -> new ArrayList<>());
```

causes a problem, but

```
doSomething((Supplier<Collection<String>> & Serializable)() -> new ArrayList<>());
```

is fine? The lambda itself is exactly the same in both cases, and in the second one it works. That means that the JVM is capable of creating serialisable lambdas, however is the compiler not able to recognise that this is possible?

Edit: changed the first call to what I intended.

Comment: `() -> ArrayList::new` is trying to implement a `Collection` via method reference. Do you mean either, `ArrayList::new` or `() -> new ArrayList<>()` instead?

Comment: Haha, yeah, my mistake, I changed `ArrayList::new` to `() -> new ArrayList<>()` to better illustrate my question, but forgot to change method reference to a call. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [JLS 15.16. Cast Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

> Casts can be used to explicitly "tag" a lambda expression or a method reference expression with a particular target type. To provide an appropriate degree of flexibility, the target type may be a list of types denoting an intersection type, provided the intersection induces a functional interface (§9.8).

and no comment why it isn't inferred automatically. My guess: it could be possible, but wasn't yet implemented. Also interesting what Eugene stated in the comments. May that mean that something similar is coming in Java 9?

Comment: The question clearly is about creating a serializable `Supplier` via lambda expression or method reference. The OP hoped that this could be inferred from the target type `T extends Supplier<Collection<String>> & Serializable`…

Comment: I suppose `() -> ArrayList::new` is just a typo. For the actual issue, it doesn’t make a difference whether `ArrayList::new` or `() -> new ArrayList<>()` is used and I suppose, the OP tried both and mangled them when writing the question, but the actual issue is that it works with the type cast, but not when letting the compiler infer the intersection type.

Comment: can't elaborate further... maybe I can continue researching later ;-)

Comment: What Holger said is what happened - I wrote it as `ArrayList::new` first and then wanted to change it to `() -> new ArrayList<>()`, but messed up.

Comment: @Holger that's interesting, the eclipse compiler (java 9) compiles the part without the cast just fine, while `javac` 8 and 9 fails.

Comment: ok... removed that part regarding the mistake... not much left in the answer now ;-) maybe it helps others to digg deeper..